# Newton's method for Bernouilli likelihood with ridge penalty

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, ridge-regression, bernoulli-distribution

I am trying to derive the gradient and hessian of logistic regression with ridge penalty. The log-likelihood should be (correct me if I am wrong):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\Big(\log{(P_i^{y_i}(1-P_i)^{1-y_i}- \lambda\beta^T\beta)}\Big)$$
where:
$$P_i = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x_i^T \beta}}$$

Is it possible to derive the gradient and hessian analytically to apply newton's method? I made it work using the autograd library from Python but I am curious about the actual analytical derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $y_i \mid x_i \stackrel{\text{indep}}\sim \text{Bern}(\theta_i)$ and then we model $g(\theta) = X\beta$ where $g = \text{logit}$ is the link function and $X$ is our $n\times p$ full rank feature matrix.

I'm going to first work out the log likelihood in terms of $\theta$, and then I'll use the assumed relationship between $\theta$ and $\beta$ to get the actual likelihood of interest.
We have
$$
\ell(\theta\mid y, x) = \log \prod_{i=1}^n \theta_i^{y_i} (1-\theta_i)^{1-y_i} \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i \log\theta_i  + (1-y_i)\log(1-\theta_i)\right) \\
= \sum_i \left(y_i \operatorname{logit}\theta_i  + \log(1 - \theta_i)\right).
$$
I'll let $h = g^{-1}$ be the inverse link function, so in this case $h(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$.

Now from $g(\theta_i) = x_i^T\beta$ we have
$$
\ell(\beta\mid y,x) = \sum_i \left(y_i \cdot x_i^T\beta  + \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{1+e^{-x_i^T\beta}}\right)\right) \\
= \sum_i \left(y_i \cdot x_i^T\beta  - \log\left(1 + e^{x_i^T\beta}\right)\right) .
$$
We can note that $\sum_i y_i x_i^T\beta = y^TX\beta$ and $\log(1 + e^x)$ is often called the [softplus function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Softplus) so I'll denote it via $\newcommand{\sf}{\operatorname{sf}}$$\sf(x)$. I'll treat $\sf$ as being vectorized, so e.g. $\sf((1,2,3)) = (\sf(1), \sf(2), \sf(3))$. This means that I can write the log likelihood as $\newcommand{\one}{\mathbf 1}$
$$
\ell(\beta\mid y, x) = y^TX\beta - \one^T\sf(X\beta)).
$$

Adding in the ridge penalty and negating the log likelihood to make this a minimization problem leads to a full objective function of
$$
f(\beta\mid y, x) = -y^TX\beta + \one^T\sf(X\beta)) + \frac{\lambda}{2} \beta^T\beta.
$$
I'm dividing $\lambda$ by $2$ just to catch the factor of $2$ that comes from taking derivatives.

Now we can do some calculus. We can work out
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\one^T\sf(X\beta) = \sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \log(1 + e^{x_i^T\beta}) \\
= \sum_i \frac{e^{x_i^T\beta}}{1 + e^{x_i^T\beta}} \cdot x_i \\
= \sum_i h(x_i^T\beta) \cdot x_i \\
= X^Th(X\beta)
$$
(I'm also vectorizing $h$ as needed). All together this means
$$
\nabla f = -X^Ty + X^Th(X\beta) +  \lambda\beta \\
= -X^T(y - \hat y) + \lambda \beta
$$
where I'm writing $\hat y = h(X\beta)$ since these are our predicted probabilities for this choice of $\beta$. If we were just doing minimum negative log likelihood, i.e. $\lambda = 0$, then a stationary point will correspond to $X^T(y - \hat y) = \mathbf 0$. This is really natural since this is saying that we've got a good $\hat\beta$ when our residuals are orthogonal to our predictors.

For the Hessian we have
$$
\nabla^2 f= \lambda I + \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} X^Th(X\beta) \\
= \lambda I + \sum_i x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} h(x_i^T\beta) \\
= \lambda I + \sum_i x_i h'(x_i^T\beta)x_i^T.
$$
Now we can use a key feature of the inverse logit, namely that $h' = h \cdot (1-h)$, to turn this into
$$
H(\beta) = \lambda I + X^T\operatorname{diag}\left[\hat y \cdot (1 - \hat y)\right]X.
$$

Note that $H$ doesn't have $y$ in it anymore. This is a feature of having used the canonical link, which is that the Hessian is equal to the expected value of the Hessian (w.r.t. the distribution of $y\mid X$) so Fisher scoring and Newton-Raphson are equivalent here.

This is also an interpretable form in that $X^T\operatorname{diag}\left[\hat y \cdot (1 - \hat y)\right]X$ is like the sample covariance matrix except each case is weighted by our confidence in it, since $\hat y_i (1 - \hat y_i)$ is the variance of a Bernoulli random variable. We then add the regularization of $\lambda I$ so we're just bounding the smallest eigenvalue away from zero and guaranteeing good conditioning.

Even without the ridge penalty we can see that $X^T\operatorname{diag}\left[\hat y \cdot (1 - \hat y)\right]X$ is positive definite, so this is a convex optimization, but if there is near-perfect separation then we can end up with $\hat y_i$ approaching near zero or one and this can make the Hessian close to singular which is an issue for inverting it in a Newton-Raphson step. The ridge penalty helps guarantee that we're never close to singular.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still wondering why should we add the penalty to the negative log likelihood and not include it in the likelihood. Adding it after is like having $e^{\lambda\beta^T\beta}$ dividing the likelihood, which is not very intuitive. Is it just a more convinient way of doing it?

Comment: @JordiA. if we want to add it to the likelihood we can interpret this as a Bayesian MAP (maximum a posteriori) estimator. If we let $\beta\sim\mathcal N(\mathbf 0, \lambda^{-1} I)$ be the prior then the posterior is $\pi(\beta\mid y, \lambda) \propto f(y\mid \beta, \lambda)\pi(\beta\mid\lambda)$. Taking the negative log gets us to the objective function that I used (up to some constants). So I'd say that there is an interpretation either way in that we can either directly penalize the log likelihood or we can think of this regularization as coming from a prior